# XPages - saving item (field) to a document

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm having a problem with saving a value to a field (either new one or existing one) to a current document which I'm selecting:

```
var selectedIDs = getComponent("viewPanel").getSelectedIds();
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByID(selectedIDs[0]);
doc.replaceItemValue("Parentid","TEST VALUE");
doc.save;
```

When I use the replaceItemValue on a new document it works ok, but this is an existing mail document which I'm trying to stamp with a value (it will be ParentID -to assign it to another document) and it simply doesn't want to work

Any sugestions ? :)

Comment: Might be an access problem: are you allowed to save the document at all? You might also want to check what the response is of the doc.save() call: true (document is saved) or false (document could not be saved).

Comment: please describe in detail what is the problem. does it raise error? how do you initialize doc variable? do you update/save doc in other event?

Comment: Re - Mark - Thanks I will check it, but I have all manager access rights to the database, so it shouldn't be a case.

Comment: Re Frantisek - The problem doesn't rise an error, it just loads the page. This script is on OK button, it's louched from a Dojo dialog box with a view (list of documents for selection). The doc variable is initialised only here: 
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByID(selectedIDs[0]) and  I don't update or save the doc in any other events, just here.

Comment: now I see... doc.save(), you have omitted parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

you are calling `doc.save`, what returns value of field "save" (or function object?). you have to call method `doc.save()`

Comment: Not so silly, common for those new and old since no error is provided by SSJS.